# Декомпилятор Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Есть проект с кучей классов и надо его декомпилировать, однако вручную с каждым классом возиться (1000+ классов) весьма затруднительно. Нельзя ли каким то образом заставить intellij декомпилить все сразу? просто сроки поджимают

Answer (score 3):

1. Сбилдите идеевский декомпилятор  [fernflower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower)
2. Запустите `java -jar fernflower.jar <path/to/classses/folder> <output>`

Результат будет лежать в папочке

[How to decompile to java files IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389006/how-to-decompile-to-java-files-intellij-idea)